# Double slit experiment in the Heisenberg picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

In the Schrödinger picture the wave function evolves and the observables stay constant. In that picture it's not too hard to imagine how does the wave function spreads interferes and diffracts, and eventually we get a detection at the screen.

I read about the Heisenberg picture recently, where the wave function remains constant and the observables evolve.

How does this constant wave function looks like?

How does the detector "evolve"? What does ensure that we don't get detection before the particle arrives?

I'm looking for ideas that help building my mental picture about Heisenberg picture observables.

Comment: Try to read > http://motls.blogspot.com/2015/04/double-slit-experiment-in-heisenberg.html?m=1 for my treatment of the double slit experiment in the Heisenberg picture.

Comment: Dear @Luboš Motl
I am interested in this study, but when I click on it, I get the message that I am not authorised to read it. Could you help me to read it? My email address is: kovacs.attila.janos@gmail.com